# Scroll to the bottom of ckeditor

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, ckeditor, textarea

any ideas on how to scroll to bottom of a ckeditor editor using javascript / jQuery?

I cant find anything.

All my search shows is:

```
document.getElementById("ID").contentWindow.scrollTo(0,3);
```

Which gives me an error of contentWindow is undefined.

The class of the ckeditor text part appears to be "cke_editable".

Any help on scrolling to the bottom of the editor?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Access the editor and get the editable area via that instead of getting the DOM element directly. Like so:

```
var editor = CKEDITOR.instances.editor1; 
var jqDocument = $(editor.document.$);
var documentHeight = jqDocument.height();
jqDocument.scrollTop(documentHeight);
```

This works in the Demo: http://ckeditor.com/demo (you need `var $ = jQuery;` if you try it in the console).

Note that your editor might not be named "editor1" - use the appropriate name for you.

Comment: @user2921557 I edited the example to actually get the document height, now it should work with dynamically sized documents. I figured that 999999 would have been enough and/or you would have set it as you like, but this way is definitely more dynamic.